# How do I use t-distribution with glm() in R?

Tags: r, glm

I've established pretty conclusively that the residuals I'm generating with a standard `lm()` regression can be reasonably modeled by a t-distribution with 6-ish degrees of freedom.  I'd like to use `glm()` with that error model, but I'm not seeing that the t fits into one of the families.  Any recommendations on either alternatives to `glm()` that play well with t, or a family that would serve reasonably well as a substitute for (or superset of) t?

Comment: "errors"....do you mean residuals?

Comment: Yes, I mean residuals...

Comment: GLMs do not assume the distribution of the residuals, so that point is moot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `heavy` can perform t-student regression models. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
library(heavy)
data(ereturns)
fit <- heavyLm(m.marietta ~ CRSP, data = ereturns, family = Student(df = 6))
summary(fit)
# Linear model under heavy-tailed distributions
# Data: ereturns; Family: Student(df = 2.83727) 
# 
# Residuals:
#  Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
# -0.142237 -0.036156  0.003433  0.041310  0.546533 
# 
# Coefficients:
#  Estimate Std.Error Z value p-value
# (Intercept) -0.0072   0.0082   -0.8876  0.3748
# CRSP         1.2637   0.1902    6.6459  0.0000
# 
# Degrees of freedom: 60 total; 58 residual
# Scale estimate: 0.002520795
# Log-likelihood: 71.81294 on 3 degrees of freedom
```

Comment: Huzzah!  I will investigate that and get back to the assemblage!

Comment: I've installed Heavy, and am running into a puzzling problem:  when I run heavyLm() I'm getting the message `Warning message:
In lsfit(x, y, intercept = FALSE) : 'X' matrix was collinear`, and when I call `summary` on the results, I receive the error `Residuals:
Error in quantile.default(resid) : 
  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
`

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your data. Some variables might be 100% correlated. But I cannot know without looking at your data. I suggest you post a different question if you want to ask about this one and add a reproducible example.

Comment: I've confirmed that there are no collinear columns by applying caret::findLinearCombos() to all of the numeric columns, so I'm completely confused.

Comment: Ok, figured that out, I had a dummy column that was redundant to a factor.  Silly me, it's gone now...